# Are all planets conquerable?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Just like the title says.

Are all planets conquerable or are there also planets that cannot be conquered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, not all planets are conquerable.

The starter planets, capital worlds, Manaan, and post-Ziost planets are not conquerable. All other planets can be conquered. You do see the message `No guild controls this sector` on the unconquerable planets.

Planets that can't be conquered:

- Ord Mantell
- Tython
- Hutta
- Korriban
- Coruscant
- Dromund Kaas
- Manaan
- Ziost
- Zakuul
- Odessen

Planets that can be conquered:

- Alderaan
- Balmorra (both factions)
- Belsavis
- Corellia
- Hoth
- Ilum
- Makeb
- Nar Shadda
- Quesh
- Taris (both factions)
- Tatooine
- Voss
- Rishi
- Yavin 4

Some of the daily areas/moons are also conquerable:

- The Black Hole
- Section X
- CZ-198
- Oricon